# ActivityNotFoundException when try to open pdf file in android application

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, report, android-manifest

I'm new to android development. I'm trying to create a PDF file using android application and view through the application.there is no error when i creating the pdf file, but it throws and exception when i try to open the pdf file. I also set the read and write permission in the manifest file.
here is my method to open the pdf file

```
void openPdf()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

    File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");
    intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
    startActivity(intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" ));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    Intent target = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
    try {
        startActivity(target);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ActivityNotFoundException:" + e);
    } 
}
```

this the error that i get

```
 03-28 05:47:59.760: E/AndroidRuntime(5844): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard/PDF/demo.pdf typ=application/pdf }
```

here is my manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.isuru.mypdf"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.isuru.mypdf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

why this error comes,please help me to solve the problem. weather i have to change the cored or add some cording. thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check on your phone/Emulator that PDF opening application (Any app having Mapped action with "android.intent.action.VIEW") is installed or not. If not please install adobe reader or any pdf opening app and try again.

Comment: you mean that i have to install pdf opening app for my Emulator,how to do this?

Comment: You have to install only so that your app can use this installed app to open you PDF

Comment: download kingsoft office from http://www.kingsoftstore.com/download-office/android-office-apps.html and install that apk into your emulator for testing.. To instal apk in emulator "adb install kingsoftapp.apk"

Comment: thank you thank you very much , i solve the problem. i think that was a problem of my cording now it works, i spend two days for this simple matter .